# calling React function from another script and render it in Canvas

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, three.js, react-three-fiber

it's been weeks since i started this fun project..

and i think it's about time i tidy up a bit.

so i have this function that renders 3d models into canvas

main.jsx

```
   const [clothesCurrent, clothesModel] = useState("cModel1");

   const cModels = {

        cModel1: <C1 />,
        cModel2: <C2 />,
    }
    const CChange1 = () => {
        clothesModel("cModel1");
    }
    const CChange2 = () => {
        clothesModel("cModel2");
    }

  return(
    <div>
      <Navigation />
      <h3>Change Clothes</h3>
      <button onClick={CChange1}>Clothes1</button>
      <button onClick={CChange2}>Clothes2</button>
      <Canvas>
        <Suspense>
          {cModels[clothesCurrent]}
        </Suspense>
      </Canvas>
    </div>
  )
```

but then i create navbar and decided to migrate all the function there, with a simple minded thought i does it like this

Navbar.jsx

```
export default function Navigation() {
}

function Navbar(props) {
}

function NavItem(props) {
}

function DropdownMenu() {
  return(
    <div>
      <DropdownItem leftIcon={<BoltIcon />} onClick={<CChange1 />}>Hair 1</DropdownItem>
      <DropdownItem leftIcon={<BoltIcon />} onClick={<CChange2 />}>Hair 2</DropdownItem>
    </div>
  )
```

but this just wrong, and have tried modify `const cChange` to `export function CChange()` outside the main function and it still wont work. can you guys give me solution? thank you!

Heres the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-thunder-epjpcz?file=/src/Main.js)